# css transition: background-color and width 'cancel' each other?

Tags: css, transition

I'm trying to change div **background-color** and **width** on mouse hover. However, can't make it both work, changing bg-color works but changing width in 3 sec does not. CSS code:

```
div {
    background-color:gold;
    width:100px;       
    transition: width 3s ease;
    transition: background-color 3s ease;
}

div:hover{
    background-color:#f00;
    width:200px;  
  }
```

Fiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/f61ashbu/
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Use transition: all 3s ease in your css

Comment: You can't have two properties with the same name in the same CSS rule. The property written last overrides all the preceding copies and only its value would apply. But some properties, including `transition`, can have multiple values, comma-separated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Use CSS **transition:3s ease;**

**see snippet**

```css
div {
    background-color:gold;
    width:100px;       
    transition:3s ease;
}

div:hover{
    background-color:#f00;
    width:200px;  
  }
```

```html
<div>
  Lorem...
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to write multiple transitions as one rule seperated by commas

```css
div {
  background-color: gold;
  width: 100px;
  transition: width 3s ease, background-color 3s ease;
}

div:hover {
  background-color: #f00;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  Lorem...
</div>
```

You can also use `transition: all 3s ease`, but this will animate other properties used in `:hover`.

Answer (score 1):

use `transition: all;`

```css
div {
    background-color:gold;
    width:100px;       
    transition: all 3s ease;
}

div:hover{
    background-color:#f00;
    width:200px;  
  }
```

```html
<div>
  Lorem...
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You overwrite your first declaration but you want to execute both, so you have to seperate it with `,`.

```
transition: background-color 3s ease, width 3s ease;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using all as the [transition-property] as right now you are selecting only the background-color.

```
transition: all 3s ease;
```